# Android release management process

Tags: android, web-services, build

I have a android application which is using a external web service. I have 3 environments to test this application . (Dev,Staging & Production servers). Currently i have included the web service URL in the code & i only can connect to one server at a time. When i need to change it i have to build the application again.. So is there any way to do this customization?

Its better that if i can make 3 applications with 3 different URL at the build time. Is there any chance of way to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if you could not find maybe you can use [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) for that